# Loop around an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, increment

Let's say I have an Array:

```
arr[3]={0,1,2};
```

and I am generating a Random value:

```
int r = Random.Range(0,4);
```

And in my code just after that I want to use:

```
print(arr[r-1]+arr[r]+arr[r+1]);
```

In this case it will only work if arr[r] is 1, because if r=0 then r-1 will be -1 , what can I do so if I increment the last index, it goes back to a certain point? 
So that if r=2, so arr[r]=2, arr[r+1]=0 , and arr[r+4] is also 0 because it did an extra loop.

I know I could use ifs, if r=0 then r-1=3 but it's less than ideal.
Thanks

Comment: you can use modulo `%`

Comment: Valid, runable C# code would be useful.

Comment: Also, no matter what `r` you chose the code `arr[r-1]+arr[r]+arr[r+1]` will always add to `3` (once you figure out how to loop around the array). **Real code would be useful**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that I think you can work with:

```
var random = new Random();

var arr = new [] { 0, 1, 2 };

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int r = random.Next(1, 1 + arr.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", (r - 1) % 3, r % 3, (r + 1) % 3));
}
```

That produces:

```
1, 2, 0
2, 0, 1
2, 0, 1
1, 2, 0
2, 0, 1
2, 0, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
2, 0, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
2, 0, 1
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
0, 1, 2
1, 2, 0
1, 2, 0
0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try modulus %. I'm not too sure if the operation will always return a positive value, but you can always do `r = random.range(3,7);`, and then use `r-1 % 3` etc.